# The content is blocked because it isn't signed by a valid security certificate error in Outlook addin

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an Outlook add-in which is required to open an authentication dialog before performing a job. I am facing two issues which I think are inter-related.

1. Though the add-in works fine in Edge and Chrome, the dialog doesn't appear in IE. I don't see any error in the console also regarding this.
2. I see below error when it tries to open the dialog.
   [image]

I am installing the certificates using `npx office-addin-dev-certs install`, and have already re-installed them as recommended in different forums. Also, my Outlook version is up-to-date.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you send us the Outlook build number? To get this, please go to File > Office Account tab > 'About Outlook' section. You most likely have to add the domain(s) to the list of trusted sites in IE, by adding them under IE's Internet Options > Security > Trusted Sites menu.

Comment: The build number is 13231.20514 (Version 2009). 
I have added the domains in the trusted site lists but that the issue persists

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 1903 or higher? If so you should be in Edge (original) engine instead of IE. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins  Also to confirm, you addin works in Outlook on the web in Edge and Chrome, but not Windows Outlook?

Comment: Yes, it is Windows 10 1903 version. That is correct, the adding works in Outlook (Edge and Chrome) but not on Windows Outlook and IE

Comment: It sounds like the add-in loads correctly, but the dialog doesn't? If you open the dialog's URL directly in IE (outside of Outlook), does IE show a certificate error (double-check that the add-in's initial URL loads too)? Is the dialog's domain included the [AppDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain) section of the add-in manifest?

Comment: The issue was due to a certificate error for an URL that was getting redirected from the dialog. It got resolved now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

For me issue happened after Windows 10 update, certs went old.

Fix is deleting content of folder `C:\Users\{username}\.office-addin-dev-certs` and running command `npx office-addin-dev-certs install` in order to renew certs.

Further info here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/1598

Answer (score 2):

This can be happened after windows 10 update.

Please delete C:\Users{username}.office-addin-dev-certs folder
and execute "**npm run start**"

Then it is automatically that generates new certs on same folder

This is only suitable for the localhost only

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 11 I couldn't get this to work. I tried deleting `C:\Users\{username}\.office-addin-dev-certs` and reinstalling with `npx office-addin-dev-certs install` but that didn't work. I even went to `Internet Options` -> `Advanced` and disabled `Check for publisher's certificate revocation` and `Check for server certificate revocation`:

[image]

...but that still didn't fix the problem.

The only way I got this to work was to run [Fiddler Classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic). As soon as I opened Fiddler, it started to work. I believe this is because access to https://localhost:3000 gets proxied through Fiddler and Fiddler uses its own self signed certificate (which gets installed when you enable the `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` option in Fiddler).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried many ways, but I failed all of them.

I don't understand well, but anyway, I solved it by changing the security settings of Internet Explorer.

Internet Explorer (not Edge) -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security ->
"Check for server certificate revocation"

make sure uncheck this options, and then reboot.

Please refer to this link for further adjustment.
https://appuals.com/fix-content-was-blocked-because-it-was-not-signed-by-a-valid-security-certificate/

Answer (score 0):

After windows update, `npx office-addin-dev-certs install` generated certificate isn't recognized by edge browser. Even though there is dialog which says that the import is successful, the imported certificate wouldn't show up in browser certificate collection list. I have created new SSL certificate using openssl and made sure that the following properties are set:

1. Issued to and Issued by properties should be same i.e., localhost
2. Make sure that subject is set to localhost as well
3. Subject alternative name should also be set as localhost `DNS Name=localhost`

This helped me to fix the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/71487759/6491417