# SelfSignedCertificate not accepted in MS Edge (Win 10)

Tags: windows, ssl, microsoft-edge, self-signed

To get Edge to trust the localhost development server, I created a selfsigned certificate following this [tutorial](https://zeropointdevelopment.com/how-to-get-https-working-in-windows-10-localhost-dev-environment/). I just replaced all instances of client-1.local by localhost.

So in short, I created a trusted authority by creating a .pem-file with the commands

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out rootSSL.key 2048
```

and then

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootSSL.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootSSL.pem
```

and imported those into the trusted authorities store in the MMC.

Then I created a private key with

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out localhost.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -subj "/C=AU/ST=NSW/L=Sydney/O=Client One/OU=Dev/CN=localhost/emailAddress=local@local.com"
```

and a certificate with

```
openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA rootSSL.pem -CAkey rootSSL.key -CAcreateserial -out localhost.crt -days 50000 -sha256 -extensions "authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer\n basicConstraints=CA:FALSE\n keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment\n  subjectAltName=DNA:localhost"
```

The certificate shows up as valid when double clicking on it.

For the exception I need to import the certificate into the browsers. For Firefox I got at first the error

```
You do not own the private key for the certificate
```

So I created a PKCS12 file

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey ./sample.key -in ./sample.crt -out ./sample.p12
```

and imported that one in Firefox under "My Certificates". That works, I host with *ng serve "ssl/localhost.crt"* and Firefox with the imported *.p12* accepts my localhost. Now for MS Edge it still complains, my certificate is not valid.

I also tried *.pfx*-merging, but no change. I also read the certificates should not be installed under My Certificates but as Authorities. That sounds wrong to me but I tried it and imported both the *.crt* and the *.p12* into *Authorities* and *Root Authorities*, because why not, but no change. I also installed the certificate through the Windows Wizard.

What am I missing for MS Edge? I sadly have no way around it.

===== Update =====

Additional information:

Edge does not give any helpful error. [Here](https://api.leeway.tech/edge%20error___m6n84jd9.PNG) is an image of the message. It is in German but all it says is the default text "The connection is not secure. The certificate is invalid. Your credit card information might be stolen." If there is some way to get a more informative message for Edge I would be very happy. In the developer console the message is:

> This site does not have a valid SSL certificate! Without SSL, your site's and visitors' data is vulnerable to theft and tampering. Get a valid SSL certificate before  releasing your website to the public.

The certificate files and the output of `openssl x509 -text localhost.crt` can be viewed [here](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/SUKk1mxP#link) (password is pass or password, if necessary) and an image of the .crt [here](https://api.leeway.tech/ccert___1aprgqru.PNG). It is sitting in my development folder, I host the site with

```
ng serve --ssl true --ssl-cert \"ssl/localhost.crt\" --ssl-key \"ssl/localhost.key\"
```

and access the server locally through localhost:3000.

I imported the .p12 file into edge through manage certificates -> My Certificates -> Import. The result looks like [this](https://api.leeway.tech/edge%20import___1qnokgve.PNG).

Comment: *"Now for MS Edge it still complains, my certificate is not valid."* - please provide the full and exact error message. Also provide the full contents of the certificate `openssl 509 -text -in sample.crt` and the URL you use to access it.

Comment: Did you add the certificate to Edge correctly? You can find the Edge certificates manager to check it. By the way, you can simply refer to [this similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-using-openssl), it may be useful to you.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you, I updated the question.S adly I cannot find any informative error in Edge, only the certficate is invalid message. I added the output of your command to a text file in the download bundle.

Comment: @user1437515: the uploaded file returns only a 404 not found error. As for the error message - there should be an "Advanced" or similar button on the browser window displaying the error message (not in the overlay window you show but in the main browser window).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ah sorry I posted the manage files link and not the download link. Not it is corrected. Sadly Edge only shows a blank white screen. In Firefox and Chrome I get the advanced infos, but I can get it running there too :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I missing for MS Edge? I

The certificate does not contain any subject alternative names, which makes it invalid for Edge and Chrome. There is an attempt to specify these information, but the attempt is wrong.

> I created a selfsigned certificate following this tutorial.

Looks like this tutorial is broken.

> openssl x509 -req ... -extensions "authorityKeyIdentifier ... subjectAltName=DNA:localhost"

The `-extension` command line option is used to give the name of an extension **section** in a configuration file and not the extensions itself. Additionally the `subjectAltName` should be `DNS:...` not `DNA:...`.

To fix create an extension file `my.ext` which includes the extensions you want to use:

```
[myext]
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName=DNS:localhost
```

Then use this file as extension file with `-extfile my.ext` and specify the extension to use with `-extensions myext`:

> openssl x509 -req ... -extfile my.ext -extensions myext

Comment: I was also someone who read 10+ tutorials, and 50+ discussions, but none with an extensions file that actually worked. Some of the answers posted here may also be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74802552/2657515