# How to correctly deploy an Excel add-in on IIS with a self signed certificate?

Tags: iis, office-js, office-addins

I have developed an Excel add-in, and trying to run it I get the following error:

[image: Cert error]

"The content is blocked because it isn't signed by a valid security certificate."

[image: Add-in's binding]

- The add-in is a taskpane developed in Visual Studio
- I've deployed the add-in with Microsoft 365 admin center
- The add-in is hosted on a server running IIS, on port 443
- I'm connected to the server via VPN.

I've tried

- creating a self-signed certificate in IIS manager, and installing it in the client machine's Trusted Root Certification Authorities
- creating a certificate in Visual Studio, importing it to IIS, installing it on the client
- adding the server's IP to the client's trusted sites
- ports 4433 and 443
- setting the add-in's binding to "All unassigned"
- something I've already forgotten

Somehow the add-in works in the web version of Excel.

Comment: This error is due to the certificate, to fix this issue you need to install this certificate on your local machine inside certificate store to accept that as valid certificate.

Comment: @samwu That is indeed the first thing I did, but no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The content is blocked because it isn't signed by a valid security certificate error in Outlook addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818707/the-content-is-blocked-because-it-isnt-signed-by-a-valid-security-certificate-e)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No, as far as I know local dev certs aren't relevant at this point, as the add-in is hosted on a remote server.

Comment: Your certificate must be trusted on your machine. Does it work correctly if you run your solution locally?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The add-in runs successfully while debugging locally in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you get this error in a web browser or desktop application?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I get the error on desktop, the add-in works without error in browser-based Excel.

Comment: Are you sure your test certificate includes the URL where your add-in is hosted, not only for localhost?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev the certificate is issued to hostname.domain.local.

Comment: Does it correspond to the one specified in the manifest file?

Comment: Yes, AppDomain, SourceLocation etc. point to the same url.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.